# Hibernate OneToOne relationship allows to save several references

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class Letter:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class Letter {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="request", targetEntity=Letter)
    Letter response;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Letter request
}
```

And two its subclasses:

```
class LetterIn extends Letter {
}

class LetterOut extends Letter {
}
```

The idea is to save LetterIn instances in fields "response" and "request" of LetterOut instances and vice versa: LetterOut instances in fields "response" and "request" of LetterIn instances.

Unfortunately Hibernate allows me to save several instances of class LetterOut with "request" fields filled with the same instance of LetterIn class.

So in database there are several LetterOut objects reference on the same LetterIn object. Then I try to load LetterIn objects and get an error:

```
More than one row with the given identifier was found: %ID%, for class: Letter
```

What should I do to prevent such situations?

Comment: Why response is annotated with `mappedBy="request"` ?

Comment: In this case if you fill LetterOut.request with an LetterIn object then LetterIn.response is filled with that LetterOut object automatically and vice versa. I need such behavior.